# Diazo CSS changes not reflected on site

Tags: plone, diazo

I have a Plone server that I'm building Diazo themes on.  The themes live in a resource directory setup via buildout.  Themes show up in Diazo control panel on site, can be enabled and all works as expected.  However, when I make any change to the CSS on the file system, these changes do not take effect on the site.

These sites are setup with a dev URL (pointing to a client that is always in development mode).  The production URL's to sites on this server are pointing to Varnish/HaProxy, load balanced between the other clients that are not in development mode.

The CSS changes are immediately available on the development URL (bypassing varnish/haproxy).  I tried clicking "save" on portal_css in the ZMI in both dev and production URLs  I tried reinstalling the theme through the Diazo control panel.  I also went as far as restarting the cluster.

My guess is that this is a plone.app.caching issue for us, but I'm unsure.

Looking at the response headers, I see the following (I believe relevent bits) for the CSS document in question:

Cache-Control   max-age=86400, proxy-revalidate, public
Date    Thu, 11 Apr 2013 19:54:33 GMT
Expires Fri, 12 Apr 2013 19:33:13 GMT
X-Cache-Operation   plone.app.caching.strongCaching
X-Cache-Rule    plone.resource

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

When Plone is in foreground (development) mode, it watches for changes in templates and other file system resources, which are all served individually. When it's not in development mode, it merges (cooks) CSS and JS resources for efficient delivery. That's only done on startup and when resource registry entries change.

For production systems, you need to restart Zope/Plone to register changes in file system resources. You *may* be able to get your changes seen by forcing the resource registry to re-cook the resources. To do that, visit portal_css in the ZMI and resubmit the resource list form.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  If I understand correctly, I believe I've done this.  By adding going to portal_css, scrolling to the bottom and clicking "save".  As a test, I renamed the css in the Diazo theme, changed the HTML doc as well to reflect this and clicked the save button in portal_css and it seemed to have worked. But it doesn't work if you just change code in the CSS.

Comment: Unless you're running in foreground mode, Plone is not going to notice the changes to the Diazo resources, including the HTML theme file.

Comment: Thats sort of unfortunate.  One of the things that appealed to me about Diazo is that it gets Plone out of its own way for design/theming.  We have a need to be able to change or add design elements to site sections "on the fly".  I was hoping to be able to accomplish this all while staying out of the ZMI.

Comment: This is only a limitation for diazo resources in Python packages. If you're using zip files uploaded via the theming configlet, it's no problem.
Also, check out the new theme editor in Plone 4.3. Diazo resources may be edited TTW.

Comment: The 4.3 migration is *very* easy.